# Passing an array of points to draw onto the canvas

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, canvas

I'm trying to pass an array of points onto a Javascript canvas.  The script is pulling the array from a JSON file.  I know for a fact that the ajax call is connecting to the JSON file, so I'm not going to include that in the question.  Here is the script and the JSON file.

**JS**

```
var x1 = result[0].back_line.x1;
var y1 = result[0].back_line.y1;
var x2 = result[0].back_line.x2;
var y2 = result[0].back_line.y2;
var stroke = result[0].back_line.stroke;
var stroke_width = result[0].back_line.width;

for(var i = 0; i < x1.length - 1; i++){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1[i], y1[i]);
    ctx.lineTo(x2[i], y2[i]);
    ctx.lineWidth = stroke_width;
    ctx.strokeStyle = stroke;
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

**JSON**

```
[{
    "back_lines": {
        "width": 6,
        "stroke": "#000000",
        "x1": [938.4, 621.283, 621.283, 604.267, 549.1, 504.233, 582.817, 582.817, 380.033, 477.5, 477.5, 379.42, 379.42, 344.73, 344.73, 588.37, 646.6, 646.6, 804.33, 804.33, 601.05, 601.05, 597.433, 597.433, 475.433, 362.467, 208.8, 191.217, 191.217, 645.017, 645.017, 866.617, 866.617, 849.25, 849.25, 849.25, 360.033, 360.033, 360.033, 209.8, 209.8, 566.5, 566.5, 611, 611, 360.033, 478.05, 793.083, 793.083, 576, 793.083, 843.32, 843.32, 478.05, 504.233, 504.233, 587.37, 646.07, 646.07, 804.43, 803.4, 622.52, 622.52],
        "y1": [258.167, 177.82, 177.82, 258.167, 257.633, 256.633, 257.9, 214.22, 214.22, 366, 484.133, 269.767, 308.82, 308.82, 557.05, 483.5, 483.5, 515, 515, 499.2, 483, 434.3, 141.667, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 586.083, 586.083, 534.783, 534.783, 515.417, 499.2, 499.2, 409.683, 111.267, 111.267, 84.383, 84.383, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 498.667, 84.383, 84.383, 84.383, 377.233, 377.233, 84.383, 84.383, 120.5, 84.383, 366, 466.15, 467.27, 467.27, 394.52, 394.52, 409.7, 467.8, 403.42],
        "x2": [868, 621.283, 621.283, 604.267, 549.1, 504.233, 582.817, 582.817, 380.033, 477.5, 477.5, 379.42, 379.42, 344.73, 344.73, 588.37, 646.6, 646.6, 804.33, 804.33, 601.05, 601.05, 597.433, 597.433, 475.433, 362.467, 208.8, 191.217, 191.217, 645.017, 645.017, 866.617, 866.617, 849.25, 849.25, 849.25, 360.033, 360.033, 360.033, 209.8, 209.8, 566.5, 566.5, 611, 611, 360.033, 478.05, 793.083, 793.083, 576, 793.083, 843.32, 843.32, 478.05, 504.233, 504.233, 587.37, 646.07, 646.07, 804.43, 803.4, 622.52,  622.52],
        "y2": [258.167, 225.45, 225.45, 258.167, 257.633, 256.633, 257.9, 214.22, 214.22, 366, 484.133, 269.767, 308.82, 308.82, 557.05, 483.5, 483.5, 515, 515, 499.2, 483, 434.3, 141.667, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 111.267, 586.083, 586.083, 534.783, 534.783, 515.417, 499.2, 499.2, 409.683, 111.267, 111.267, 84.383, 84.383, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 577.7, 498.667, 84.383, 84.383, 84.383, 377.233, 377.233, 84.383, 84.383, 120.5, 84.383, 366, 466.15, 467.27, 467.27, 394.52, 394.52, 409.7, 467.8, 403.42]
    }
}]
```

The error I'm getting is:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x1' of undefined`

However, if I don't do an array and just try to do one point, there is no error and the line is drawn onto the canvas.  **Am I looping through the arrays wrong?  Do I need to do multiple for loops for each array?  Since the array lengths are the same, I should only need to loop through one of them, right?**

Comment: should be `result[0].back_lines` no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your JS code you wrote:

```
var x1 = result[0].back_line.x1;
```

Try with

```
var x1 = result[0].back_lines.x1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I'm going to give you the upvote and accept it, but the answer was pointed out in the comments.

Comment: Thanks :) user3906922 has answered when i was typing ^^ Good luck with HTML Canvas